# Is it mandatory to give Namespace while creating custom module in Magento?

Tags: magento2

Is it mandatory to give a Namespace while creating custom module in Magento?

Comment: @arushi. What do you mean by 'no'? can you give an example.

Comment: @marius, you are right, I read it somewhere earlier. well i found out https://github.com/magento/code-migration/issues/45 today which clears my wrong illusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
This is the structure accepted by Magento2.
Each module should have a Vendor name (or namespace) and a module name.
`Namespace/Module`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, It is mandatory to give namespace.**

Because If you want to create module with same name you can create it in magento 2 but if you won't give it namespace then how it will separate two different module.

So, With `namespace` you can separate each module. which can help magento to read your module code.

**Ex. You can create your own Sales module with your different vendor name (or namespace).**

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is mandatory.

According to Magento 2.x Rules,

MEQP1 : Namespace should specified.

PSR1:  Each class must be in a namespace of at least one level.